# Calculating percentage difference between maximum and current value

Tags: data-transformation, extreme-value

I am having a set of calculations say variable x and a maximum value max(x). I want to calculate percentage difference of variable or observation x<sub>i</sub> from max(x).

What can be the most suitable formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the relative change (or difference) several indicators exists. However, the log change is the only symmetric, additive and normed indicator of relative change.

The log change is defined as:

$log_e\frac{y}{x}$

If you multiply this number by 100, you obtain the log change in percent (the log percentage) denoted by the symbol $L\%$.

You can find further details in:
L. Tornqvist, P. Vartia and Y. O. Vartia (1985), How Should Relative Changes Be Measured? The American Statistician, 39, 43-46
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2683905

Comment: But what about the case when any value is zero

Comment: Also can not the following be proper method.

$$
percentage\quad difference= \frac{max(x)-x_{i}}{max(x)}*100
$$

Comment: To first comment: If you add 1 to your variables, the variables that were zeroes on the original scale will be zeroes on the log scale. To second comment: it should be $\frac{x_i-max(x)}{max(x)} * 100$